# Asterisk HOLD functionality workaround

Tags: asterisk, webrtc

I'm using **asterisk** with **webrtc** in chrome (SIPml5 client) and also using their webrtc2sip gateway.

My problem is that I can't send the hook-flash/flash signal to asterisk for some reason.

Is there a possibility to trigger hook flash by sending **DTMF** signals ? (which apparently work for me )

Example: I want to trigger the standard hold functionality by sending the following DTMF sequence: #123.

On the other hand as a workaround, could I hold a channel using AMI or AGI  ?

Basically I want the other party to hear OnHoldMusic while the channels/call remain active. On the local side I can just mute the audio tag which is fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do hold using ami command hold or AGI exec command musiconhold

That info is availible in AMI/AGI documentation

You can handle dtmf by using features.conf